# TWM - Why can't I do anything?

Tags: server, window-manager

So I have installed TWM on Ubuntu Server edition, in virtualbox, but when I startx and enter TWM, I can't actually do anything but open the menu; if I click on anything in the menu it just closes and nothing happens. I tried an apt-get purge twm and then re-installed it but it's the exact same, I can't do anything at all. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left click for menu. Hold it down, and navigate with the mouse to Debian -> Applications, and then you will have a list similar to Windows XP's list of applications. You should have a wireframe of the window appear, so place it somewhere on the desktop

[image]